# How to solve size_t error during installtion of program in linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install The FPLO® package which is a full-potential local-orbital code to solve band structure problem. I received the installed file and i did as per instruction to install and during setup of pyfplo package as per their installation guide, it throws me error and exits. How to solve this

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:537:9: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
  537 |       , size_t
      |         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:13:1: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
   12 | #include <stdarg.h>
  +++ |+#include <stddef.h>
   13 |
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:546:9: error: ‘F77_GLOBAL’ declared as function returning a function
  546 |    void F77_srot_base(FINT, float *, FINT, float *, FINT, const float *, const float *);

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:1089:25: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:1089:33: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
 1089 |       , size_t, size_t, size_t, size_t
      |                                 ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas_f77.h:1089:33: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<stddef.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stddef.h>’?
In file included from /home/bishnu/fplo_inst/FPLO/FPLO22.00-62/LAPACK/cblas_zdotc_sub.c:11:
/home/bishnu/fplo_inst/FPLO/FPLO22.00-62/LAPACK/cblas_zdotc_sub.c: In function ‘cblas_zdotc_sub’:
/home/bishnu/fplo_inst/FPLO/FPLO22.00-62/LAPACK/cblas_zdotc_sub.c:22:4: error: ‘zdotcsub’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   22 |    F77_zdotc_sub( &F77_N, X, &F77_incX, Y, &F77_incY, dotc);
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bishnu/fplo_inst/FPLO/FPLO22.00-62/LAPACK/cblas_zdotc_sub.c:22:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/bishnu/fplo_inst/FPLO/FPLO22.00-62/LAPACK/cblas_zdotc_sub.c:22:4: error: ‘ZDOTCSUB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   22 |    F77_zdotc_sub( &F77_N, X, &F77_incX, Y, &F77_incY, dotc);
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
make: *** [Makefile:63: compileinteractive3] Error 1
```

I try to update and upgrade all packages and try to re run installatio of program and same error occurs.

Comment: Looks like the code is buggy. Complain to the authors.